# How do I Make a double jump Script that makes the power of the second Jump the Value of the players leader stat value

Tags: scripting, roblox

I made this code thinking it would allow the player to jump Twice and the second Jump be the power of its leader stat but Instead it doesn't even allow the player to Jump a second time.

```
local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local character
local humanoid

local canDoubleJump = false
local hasDoubleJumped = false
local oldPower
local time_delay = 0.2
local jump_multiplier = player.leaderstats.JumpBoost.Value

function onJumpRequest()
    if not character or not humanoid or not 
character:IsDescendantOf(workspace) or humanoid:GetState() == 
Enum.HumanoidStateType.Dead then
        return
    end

    if canDoubleJump and not hasDoubleJumped then
        hasDoubleJumped = true
        humanoid.JumpPower = oldPower * jump_multiplier
        humanoid:ChangeState(Enum.HumanoidStateType.Jumping)
    end
end

local function characterAdded(new)
    character = new
    humanoid = new:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    hasDoubleJumped = false
    canDoubleJump = false
    oldPower = humanoid.JumpPower

    humanoid.StateChanged:connect(function(old, new)
        if new == Enum.HumanoidStateType.Landed then
            canDoubleJump = false
            hasDoubleJumped = false
            humanoid.JumpPower = oldPower
        elseif new == Enum.HumanoidStateType.Freefall then
            wait(time_delay)
            canDoubleJump = true
        end
    end)
end

if player.Character then
    characterAdded(player.Character)    
end

player.CharacterAdded:connect(characterAdded)
UIS.JumpRequest:connect(onJumpRequest)
```

I expected the player to Jump Twice with the second Jump having the power of the leader stat(I only put that and this because it says it wants more detail)

Comment: I see your use of game.Players.LocalPlayer, so I would assume this code is in a LocalScript. Just to clarify, though, is this code in a Script or a LocalScript, and where is the script located?

Comment: Local script and in workspace

Answer (score 0):

`LocalScript`s do not execute in `game.Workspace`: they only run on clients, hence the term 'local'; `Script`s, on the other hand, are server-side.

You could use a `Script` to place your double-jump script--a `LocalScript`--into incoming players' character models.

```
-- Server-side Script
local players = game:GetService("Players")
local jumpScript = script:WaitForChild("JumpScript") -- Assume the double-jump script is a LocalScript called 'JumpScript'.

players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
        -- Check to make sure the character model does not already contain the double-jump script, just in case.
        local clone = char:FindFirstChild("JumpScript")
        if (not clone) then
            clone = jumpScript:Clone()
            clone.Parent = char
        end
    end)
end)
```

As a note, it is good practice to put server-side scripts like this into `ServerScriptStorage` instead of `workspace` or `Lighting`. (You can read about the safety of `ServerScriptStorage`[here](https://devforum.roblox.com/t/how-safe-is-serverscriptstorage/209036).)

Comment: If you're just going to clone it into the character, why not put the LocalScript in StarterCharacterScripts? That would do this automatically.